# ASP.NET Error: Content controls are allowed only in content page that references a master page

Tags: asp.net

I received the error in the title as a result of the following page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
<atlas:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
</atlas:ScriptManager>
```

In this page I use AJAX controls.

Comment: The clue is really in the error message for this one ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The page that you've put the content control is not a master page based page. Check the top of the page, if you've got html like

```
<html>
<body>
```

tags then the likelihood is that you've created a new page rather than a new page based off a masterpage.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue.

For my case, these 3 steps needs to be followed to fix it:

1. The .aspx file doesn't come under a MasterPage which means that this attribute is absent in the .aspx file `MasterPageFile="~/MyBasePage.Master"` like this. Make sure the attribute is there.

`<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MyBasePage.Master AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Public.Home" %>`

2. The Master page needs to have the same `ContentPlaceHolder` like this to hold the HTML

`<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentHeader" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`

3. The .aspx file needs to have a Content tag with the `ContentPlaceHolderID` same as the above `ID`

`<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentHeader" runat="server"></asp:Content>`

Answer (score 1):

Just use those lines, problem will be solved.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="YourPageCode.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProjectName.PageName" %>
<asp:Content ID="ContentId" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceholderID" runat="server">Your page content here</asp:Content>
```