# ascx working, cshtml not: content controls

Tags: asp.net, razor

This is the ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<NavigationEntryViewModel>>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="WebShop.Models.ViewModels"  %>

<%  if(Model.Count() > 0){ %>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <%  foreach(NavigationEntryViewModel entry in Model)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("Entry", entry);
            }
        %>   
    </ul> 
<%  } %>
```

And this is the new cshtml:

```
@using WebShop.Models.ViewModels

@model List<NavigationEntryViewModel>

@if(Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <ul class="navigation">
        @foreach(NavigationEntryViewModel entry in Model)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("Entry", entry);
        }        
    </ul>
}
```

Running the project with ascx is fine, but when I run it with the cshtml I get the error

> content controls are allowed only in content page that references a
>   master page

I tried to set the Layout to null, that didn´t work. I tried to comment Html.RenderPartial, that didn´t work too.

The View is invoked by

```
return View("Show", entries);
```

where entries is a list of NavigationEntryViewModel.

I´m lost, can somone please help?

Comment: the cshtml is used in another cshtml or did you use it directly? because there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233731/asp-net-error-content-controls-are-allowed-only-in-content-page-that-references)

Comment: It is used directly. I found the question you posted, but that doesn´t fit to my problem.

Comment: I don´t get it, because the ascx does not reference a master page.

Answer (score 1):

Your project seems to have both ASPx view engine pages and Razor view engine views. While MVC allow mixing them, all situations where I saw such approaches caused additional problems. 
In any way, if you want to use both view engine in your project, follow the recommendations provided in:

[ASP.NET MVC 3: Using multiple view engines in same project](https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-mvc-3-using-multiple-view-engines-in-same-project)

[Combining ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor and ASPX View Engines in One Project](http://geekswithblogs.net/wildturtle/archive/2010/10/13/combining-asp.net-razor-and-aspx-view-engines-in-one-project.aspx)

Comment: I´ll give that a shot - I´m currently working on switching all views to Razor, so that the ASPX View Engine will not be used anymore.

Comment: There can be several reasons. For example, "Entry" is an ascx control, but you render it into a Razor view, while it (or its internal controls) requires a content page. It is hard to say more precisely until I see all related views/pages/controls.  Make sure that all items in the chain starting with the Layout View (or MasterPage) that you render using PartialView or Partial methods are based only on Razor or only on ASPx view engine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is quite simple...

I converted all files to cshtml, renaming the old ones. The problem was, that the "old" viewengine still tried to load some files.

I don´t know exactly why, but after disabling it, it works fine. So, when switching from aspx to cshtml, disable the old viewengine as quickly as possible to avoid those nasty errors.

Thank you, Vladimir.